# Sharepoint Profile not reading some AD fields

Tags: active-directory, field-definition

I have on my Sharepoint Profiles some fields that are mapped to the Active Directory (Name, job title, phone etc).

I have added some info on the AD field called "Description", and when i went to map description field to a sharepoint profile field, on the dropdown where i choose the field to be mapped, i have all AD field options, except the "Description" field.

I really have no idea if it's a AD, or if the internal name of the field is different, or if it's my sharepoint that don't want to read that one field.

Is there anything i can do to make my sharepoint 'see' the Description field on my AD?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the attribute you are trying to sync with AD isn't properly mapped. This can be accomplished with the Forefront Identify Management (FIM) client tool.

The tool is located here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

A very detailed guide how to map a attribute:
http://goodbadtechnology.blogspot.com/2010/05/setting-up-pictureurl-user-profile.html

Comment: Thanks a lot aflyen, that guide was VERY useful, got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

"Description" will show up as an option if you select string (Multi-Value) Don't need to map this with FIM.